# Using structural typing and variable reassignment to bypass type checking on a function call with "named parameters"

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

```
function myFunc({ param1 }: {                                                
  param1: number;                                                            
}) {                                                                         
  // param1 is marked as mandatory in the definition, but we can bypass that 
}                                                                            

const mismatchedFunc: ({}) => void = myFunc;                                 

mismatchedFunc({}); // No compile-time error
```

I'm guessing that the reason for this behaviour stems from the structural-type nature of TypeScript, in that `{ param1: number }` structurally "fits into" `{}`.

Yet, is this not undesirable behaviour (in this particular case, or class of cases), because it largely bypasses the type checking that TypeScript provides?

Should this be filed as a bug?

**Edit 1**

As @shusson has pointed out, the behaviour (as of *v2.x*) is expected (due to trade-off), even though it is undesirable.

For the most relevant discussion regarding the roots of the issue, refer to [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1394) and a [follow-up proposal](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10717) to try and address it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things going on here:

1. [structural typing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html)

   > The basic rule for TypeScript’s structural type system is that x is compatible with y if y has at least the same members as x.
2. [bivariant function parameters](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-function-parameters-bivariant)

   > When comparing the types of function parameters, assignment succeeds if either the source parameter is assignable to the target parameter, or vice versa

example:

```
type t1 = { param1: number };
type t2 = { };

let f1 = (a: t1) => {};

let f2: (a: t2) => void = f1; // bivariant assignment

let x: t1 = { param1: 1 };
let y: t2 = {};

y = x; // because of this, f1 is assignable to f2 through bivariant assignment
x = y; // compile error

f1(x);
f1(y); // compile error

f2(x);
f2(y);
```

Comment: So bivariant function parameters are an undesirable behaviour, but one that is expected and is the result of a trade-off. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes that's my understanding. TypeScript has what their documentation calls `unsound` behaviours which were unavoidable but carefully considered. I think most of these problems are caused because TypeScript is coupled to JavaScript (which in my opinion is a good thing).